# Understanding parameters of strlen in C

Tags: c, for-loop, pointers, c-strings, strlen

I am a bit confused on why my code is not iterating a string in C programming.

Essentially.

I have this function here

```
int atoi(const char *s[]){
    printf(" The length is  %d",strlen(s));

    int length = strlen(s);

    for(int i = 0; i< length; ++i){
        printf("This is %s",*(s+i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My first question

1. When doing `strlen(s)` why does it work, but when doing `strlen(*s)` it does not work, isn't `strlen` supposed to be taking in the value not the pointer so the latter should work?
2. How would I go about looping through the pointer that points to the string in memory?

Cheers

Comment: Khandkar Islam, Save time.  Enable all compiler warnings to get rapid feedback.

Comment: Please show how you call this function. The code posted is not valid C but you may also have invalid C on the caller side, explaining why "it works". Also check out [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)

Comment: Read your compiler warnings

Comment: "isn't strlen supposed to be taking in the value not the pointer" That can be answered immediately by looking up the documentation of `strlen`: `size_t strlen(const char *s);`

Answer (score 2):

1. Do not use standard function names
2. `strlen` takes a pointer to `char` and returns **`size_t`** (not int)
3. Your print format is wrong.
4. Your function takes an array of pointers not a pointer to `char`

```
int myfunc(const char *s)
{
    size_t length = strlen(s);

    printf(" The length is  %zu", length);
    for(size_t i = 0; i< length; ++i){
        printf("This is '%c'\n",*(s+i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For starters you should not name your user-defined functions the same ways as standard C functions.

There is already standard C function with the name `atoi` declared in header `<stdlib.h>`. Using the same name can result in compiler or linker errors.

Your function `atoi` declared like

```
int atoi(const char *s[]){
```

that is the same as

```
int atoi(const char **s){
```

due to adjusting by the compiler a parameter having an array type to pointer to the array element type accepts a "double" pointer.  So using the function `strlen` with the double pointer invokes undefined behavior

```
printf(" The length is  %d",strlen(s));
```

The function `strlen` expects an argument of the type `char *` or `const char *` but not an argument of the type `const char **`.

Moreover the return value of the function `strlen` has the type `size_t`. And using the conversion specifier `%d` in a call of `printf` with a corresponding argument expression of the type `size_t` again invokes undefined behavior. You have to use the conversion specifier `%zu` instead of `%d`.

This for loop

```
for(int i = 0; i< length; ++i){
    printf("This is %s",*(s+i));
}
```

does not make sense because the variable `length` actually does not contain the number of elements in the passed array.

You need either explicitly to pass the number of elements in the array or the array should have a sentinel value.

And the return type of the function `int` also does not make sense because the returned value `0` reports nothing useful to the caller of the function.

If the function is designed only to traverse a string in a for loop then it should be declared like for example

```
char * func( const char *s )
{
    for ( const char *p = s; *p != '\0'; ++p )
    {
        putchar( *p );
    }

    return ( char * )s;
}
```

If you want to pass to the function an array of strings then the function can be implemented for example the following way as shown in the demonstration program below provided that the array contains a sentinel value

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func( const char **s )
{
    for ( ; *s != NULL; ++s )
    {
        printf( "%s ", *s );
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    const char * s[] = { "Hello", "World!", NULL );        

    func( s );
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello World!
```

Answer (score 1):

**Question:**

> when doing strlen(s) why does it work, but when doing strlen(*s) it
> does not work?

**Answer:**

`strlen()` expects an argument of type `const char *`, not a `const char **`. You passed an array of pointers to `char` to the function, which decayed to a `char **`. From the man page:

> The strlen() function calculates the length of the string pointed
> to by s, excluding the terminating null byte ('\0').

**Question:**

> How would I go about looping through the pointer that points to the
> string in memory?

```
printf("This is %s",*(s+i));
```

**Answer:**

Assuming you wanted to pass a string (an array of null-terminated bytes) to the function and print it `char` by `char`, change the function declaration to take a `const char *`, and use the correct format specifier in the call to `printf()` (The `%s` format specifier expects a pointer to `char`, not a `char` itself). Change the call to:

```
printf ("%c", *(s + i));
```

Note that `*(s + i)` is equivalent to `s[i]`, which is more readable. So the above call to `printf()` can be rewritten as:

```
printf ("%c", s[i]);
```

Aside: `strlen()` returns `size_t`, not an `int`. Do not mismatch numeric types.

Comment: "Because strlen() expects a const char *, not a char" But `s` is (adjusted to) type `const char**`. The code contains constraint violations, it isn't valid C. Overall your answer seems to think the parameter was `const char*`, which it wasn't.